# MySQL last line challenge when using a cursor to assemble prepared statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, database-cursor

I'm using a cursor to build a prepared statement and that works pretty good (actually better than expected).
But i can't wrap my head around the "last line challenge" what i'd like to call it for now.
I need to add a fake SELECT to the last line of the statement so that the query doesn't end with a 'semicolon'.

```
    OPEN cEmployeeSkill;

    -- loop through temp table
    getLine: LOOP
        FETCH cEmployeeSkill INTO vSkill;

        IF vFinished = 1 THEN
            SET @StatementTemp = CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN Skill_id = 0 THEN SkillLevelName END) AS \Dummy\' ');
            SET @StatementMain = CONCAT(@StatementMain,@StatementTemp);
            LEAVE getLine;
        END IF;

        -- get the current title of the skill
        SET @ColumnTitle = (SELECT SkillName FROM tbl_Skill WHERE Skill_id = vSkill GROUP BY SkillName LIMIT 1);

        -- do the pivot thing
        SET @StatementTemp = CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN Skill_id = ',vSkill,' THEN SkillLevelName END) AS \'',@ColumnTitle,'\', ');

        -- add the new line to the statment
        SET @StatementMain = CONCAT(@StatementMain,@StatementTemp);

    END LOOP getLine;

    CLOSE cEmployeeSkill;
```

Any ideas on how i can avoid adding the 'dummy' column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, just chop off the last two characters to lose the last comma:

```
SET @StatementMain = LEFT(@StatementMain, LEN(@StatementMain)-2);
```

Comment: You made my day! I had to replace LEN with LENGTH but other than that absolutely perfect.